# Is it possible to use express-handlebars tags inside an HTML script tag on the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, express-handlebars

I have been struggling with this issue for quite some time now. I'm creating an application using express-handlebars and the biggest part of the application works well. Most of the data I want to display on the webpages I'm making is displayed well and I am taking good use of the Helper functions of the express-handlebars module to do so.

Now, the part where I'm stuck is the following. In one of the HTML templates I use in my application, I am using a  tag to display a map with several locations on it using the Google Maps JS API. These locations are coming out of a MongoDB database, just like all of the other template-data I am showing on this page. 
The data is coming to the client side here as an array of objects over which I want to iterate, filter out the addresses, geocode them to the correct format and display them in the Map. The problem here is that I can get this array into the page just fine, but I can't get inside of the  as an object through which I can iterate.

Is there any way I can get this array of locations inside the script tags, so I can iterate over them to display them inside of the Map view?

Comment: Is your script embedded within the HTML or is it an external script being pulled in with an `src` tag?

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn the script is embedded in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this within the template itself:

- `var data = JSON.stringify(location_data)`
- `var script = 'var data = ' + data`

And then inside of your script tag:

- include the 'script' variable
- write the rest of your client-side code

I'm not super familiar with handlebars syntax, but I know that you can do something similar using express and pug :)

That said, it might just be easier (and cleaner) to request the map data on the client side using an xmlhttp request/ajax?